# How to find the difference between two dates in No. of days:Hours:Minutes Format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to Find Time Difference between Two dates
 for example if Date one:06-06-2015 04:10:10  Date Two:10-06-2015 05:12:10 ,Answer should be like  04:01:02. Number of day:-  The exact days difference between two date. if days count exceeds 365 years can be added. Final format should be in String. Number of days fields refer the exact day difference between two  days.

I tried The below code .

```
int noofdays=00;
int Hours=00;
int min=00;
if(item.StandardWorkingTime!=null && item.
 noofdays = (int)(d1.Subtract(d2)).TotalDays;
 Hours = (in)(d1.Subtract(d2)).TotalHours;
 min=(int)(d1.Subtract(d2)).TotalMinutes;
```

but it gives error.
can anyone please help to me to find the solution.

Comment: sshare your error please

Comment: Use TimeSpan class. It hass al the properties you need.

Comment: But the above code gives  time difference in days, hours ,miutes, Its not the actual result.i need exact difference days:hours:minutes format

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( 75 );

 TimeSpan timeSpan= endTime.Subtract(startTime);
 //span.Seconds
 //span.Minutes
 //span.Hours
 //span.Days
```

Comment: it is recommended to avoid code only answers...

Comment: Not in this example. It is self explanatory.